# Using a lance while on a charging horse against ground based enemy

Tags: warfare, medieval

This might be the wrong category to ask in. If it is, I apologize and hope you will be so kind as to point me to the right one.

I am providing editorial services for a friend writing a fantasy novel. In it he had a guy using a lance against multiple enemies while on a charging horse. My brain hiccuped at that, which usually signifies the need for an editor note, but I wanted to double check. A Google search provider mostly information about that scenario in a table top game.

So, if a guy is using a lance while on a horse, how long before it becomes a liability by getting someone stuck on the end of it, or getting snagged on a body and ripped out of your hands, possibly destabilizing the rider in the process?

In this case, it's a rabble near a dock facing a different enemy who has now been surprised from behind by light Calvary. The writer had the lead horseman making it all the way to the dock, using his lance as a weapon to "take down anyone not fast enough to get out of the way". But if the horse is moving at a brisk pace, isn't he going to lose the lance after only a few pokey pokey stab stabs?

Comment: I would think this question would be more appropriate for http://history.stackexchange.com/ unless there are some special features of this lance that are different from the historical lance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me lances were most commonly used in a charge by several knights and not by just one. It is a great weapon for breaking up the lines of the enemy, but even then the lances would break or get stuck in armour and shields. Lances would get discarded after the first charge and knights would take to their swords.

In the situation you are describing the lance seems out of place to me and also superfluous. The lance is a weapon for the battle field, not for investigating the docks. Also, people described as "rabble" sound like the sort of people who would be possible to rout with horse alone.

In any case I believe you are right in your assessment. The lance would (unless it is a lazer lance of course,) get stuck in the first person it scewered. And if the rider continued the lance would likely break, get pulled from his hands, or pull him out of the saddle.

For the effect your friend is looking for some kind of club or mace would do far better than a lance. Then he could really "take down anyone not fast enough to get out of the way".

Comment: The key thing with the lance wasn't that it was the knight's primary weapon, merely there leading weapon. Often broken/discarded after the first charge the knight would then rely on their hammer/axe/sword to do the actual fighting. That and against unarmoured rabble - the horse would be his best weapon.

Comment: Also important to note that a knight expecting to fight from horseback would have several weapons slung from his saddle as he would be prepared to lose some in combat.

Comment: Roman cavalry used long spears in a manner similar to a lance, but for close quarters essentially stabbed down at foot soldiers and other dismounted enemies. Obviously the horse isn't going very fast at that point. Riding down a dock, horsemen would be going at a walk to prevent themselves from falling off the end, a "wall" of horses 2 or 3 abreast would act more like a bulldozer and "push" people out of the way, with the lances used as prods to encourage slow movers

Answer (score 1):

Outright impaling someone is a tricky business, especially if they're wearing some sort of armour, rather I imagine he would get a lot of glancing blows which will still take plenty of people out of the fight, imagine taking a glancing hit from a pointed sledgehammer.

He might get unlucky and lose his lance but for the most part he's not aiming to impale the target and the target is trying their best not to be impaled, indeed most people (who see it coming) will successfully dodge the attack.

But if he really wants to charge through tearing great chunks out of people like something out of an anime the lance should be heavier than usual, with more mass there's more inertia so less impact force is received by the wielder, although lances were already designed to be fairly heavy for this very reason.